# Copy Infopath Repeating table row

Tags: infopath

I am beginner in Infopath, I want to copy a repeating table row  to the below of copied row using a Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (it defaults each new inserted row field with the value of the same field in the preceeding row)

on the field properties of the field you want to copy to, click the '*function*' button next to the default value.

in the insert formula dialog window check *'Edit Xpath'*

then type: ../preceding-sibling::my:{row-name}[1]/my:{field-name}

then *OK* until you get back to the form